# Remove class name start with specific text

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have a html and the class is generated by jquery on load.

```
<div class="box-1234 mainDiv"></div>
```

everytime the "1234" at the class name is generated in different number.
How should i remove the class start with "box" using jquery?
Note: the class="mainDiv" need to remain there.

Had using the following but it didnt work.

```
$('[class^="box-"]').removeClass();
```

Thanks.

Comment: $('div[class^="box"]').removeClass(function() {
return $( this ).attr( "class" );
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `box-xxxx` is always at the beginning of the class, then you could do like below:

```
$('[class^="box-"]').removeClass(function(index, className) {
    return (className.match(/(^|\s)box-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

Comment: if box-xxxx comes the second class, this will not work. so, ^= should be *=,

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var cl =  $('div').attr("class").split(" ");
var newcl =[];
for(var i=0;i<cl.length;i++){
    r = cl[i].search(/box-+/);
    if(r)newcl[newcl.length] = cl[i];
}
$('div').removeClass().addClass(newcl.join(" "));
```

this will get all class and search for all class starts with `box-` and remove from array, then remove All class and add other class ;)

Answer (score 0):

use  `.removeClass(function(index, css) {})` API

```
$('div[class*="box"]').removeClass(function (index, css) {
    return (css.match(/\bbox-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
})
```

please see Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99o68ds2/2/)